# How to filter by Desc in Javascript after ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, filter

[image]

Ajax response I am getting results like this:

```
"students":[{
"student_id":"27",
"job_id":"12",
"128":"8",
"63":"9",
"3":"10",
"weightage":"5.6000"}
,{"student_id":"22",
"job_id":"12",
"128":"5",
"63":"6",
"3":"8",
"weightage":"9.1000"
}]}
```

From this I want to show same order as the weightage (overall score) is high it should come in top lesser one in last.

How can I filter by Desc?
This is my code:

```
console.log(response['students']);
$.each(response['students'], function(k, student) {                 
    $("#stu"+student.student_id).removeClass('btn-danger reject-student');                  
    $("#stu"+student.student_id).addClass('btn-success select-student');                    
    $("#stu"+student.student_id).text('Student Selected');                  
});             
/*Sorting select-student students at one place starts here*/                
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr.sorted');              
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {                 
    if (rows[i].querySelector('span.reject-student')) {                     
        rows[i].closest('tbody').appendChild(rows[i]);                      
    }                   
}               
/*Sorting select-student students at one place ends here*/
```

Comment: When you say "filter", do you mean "sort"? And "desc" means "descending"? (Your question title "filter by Desc" sounds like you want to filter out data based on a description field...)

Comment: sorry i mean sort

Comment: why don't you sort the array using asort in server side and then send the response in json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple. Parse your response JSON string into an object. Please try the following:

```
// Array of student objects
var students = JSON.parse("Your response json string");

//Sort this array by weightage property in descending order
students.sort(function(a,b){
   return b.weightage - a.weightage; // descending order
});
```

See the fiddle below:

```js
var response = '[{"student_id": "27","job_id": "12","128": "8","63": "9","3": "10","weightage": "5.6000"}, {"student_id": "22","job_id": "12","128": "5","63": "6","3": "8","weightage": "9.1000"}]';

var students = JSON.parse(response);

students.sort(function(a,b){
   return b.weightage - a.weightage; // descending order
});

alert(students[0].weightage);
alert(students[1].weightage);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is working. I have updated my answer. Please see teh fiddle :) Please mark it as answer and upvote if it helps you. Thanks :)

Comment: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: Your Json string is not valid. Please see the valid json format in given fiddle. Thanks :)

Comment: This is the valid json string. Please compares your with this: var response = '[{"student_id": "27","job_id": "12","128": "8","63": "9","3": "10","weightage": "5.6000"}, {"student_id": "22","job_id": "12","128": "5","63": "6","3": "8","weightage": "9.1000"}]';

Comment: Is this code only for two results are not numbers because you wrote a,b in function that is the reason I'm asking

Comment: No. This is not. This is callback for sort function. It will compare two values and then sort accordingly the whole array. It doesnt matter whatever the length of your array.

Comment: @Qasim can you see my question JavaScript in that I wrote sorting stundnts based on the classes and I want to sort them based on the weightage as well.can you please help me out. Having trouble while append

Comment: @AbdulWaheed - Yes. The solution I provided sorts your array by weightage in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr.sorted');      
$.each(response['students'], function(k, student) {     
    $("#stu"+student.student_id).removeClass('btn-danger reject-student');                  
    $("#stu"+student.student_id).addClass('btn-success select-student');                    
    $("#stu"+student.student_id).text('Student Selected');  
    /*  Sorting by student overall score starts here   */
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {                 
        if (rows[i].querySelector('span#stu'+student.student_id)) {                     
            rows[i].closest('tbody').appendChild(rows[i]);                      
        }                   
    }
    /*  Sorting by student overall score ends here   */
});
```